# Python File Not Found error using pd.read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python on a windows10 PC. I am attempting to open a file in Python and I am getting a FileNotFoundError

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sergi\Downloads\covid_19_data.cvs')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error is clear: that file doesn't exist.  What makes you think the file is actually there?

Comment: Show us the output of this: `import os; print(os.listdir(r'C:\Users\sergi\Downloads'))`

Comment: is it supposed to be .csv or .cvs?